# Expressing matrix group as a semidirect product: matrix multiplication is reversed

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, semidirect-product

I am trying to determine the group that the set of matrices of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & a \\ 
0 & 1 & b \\ 
0 & 0 & c 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $a, b, c \in \mathbb{F},\, c \ne 0$ forms under multiplication. I should be getting a semidirect product $(\mathbb{F}^2,+) \rtimes \mathbb{F}^*$, but when you multiply $(a,b,c)$ by $(a',b',c')$, the terms don't line up. If $z, z'$ correspond to matrices $A, B$, then the only way I can get it to be a semidirect product is to have $z \circ z'$ correspond to $BA$, not $AB$. Is this expected?

To be more precise,
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & a' \\ 
0 & 1 & b' \\ 
0 & 0 & c' 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & a \\ 
0 & 1 & b \\ 
0 & 0 & c 
\end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & a+a'c \\ 
0 & 1 & b+b'c \\ 
0 & 0 & cc' \
\end{bmatrix},
$$
so letting $x = (a,b),\, y = c$ we get
$(x,y) \circ (x',y') = (x+yx',yy')$,
which means the homomorphsim $H \to \text{Aut}(N)$ with $H = F^*,\, N = (F^2, +)$ is given by $y \to yI_2$.

Also, for $F = F_2, F_3, F_4$ is there a way to remove the direct product? $F_2$ makes it boil down to $Z_2^2$ and for $F_3, F_4$ we get $Z_2 \rtimes Z_3^2,\, Z_3 \rtimes Z_2^4$ respectively, but I'm not sure whether this can simplify further.

Comment: You can express the $A\rtimes_{\phi} B$ in two ways: as pairs $(a,b)\in A\times B$ with multiplication given by $(a,b)(x,y) = (a\phi(b)(x),by)$; or as pairs $(b,a)\in B\times A$ with multiplication given by $(b,a)(y,x) = (by,\phi(y)(a)x)$. Here you want the latter: $(c',(a',b'))(c,(a,b)) = (c'c,(a'c,b'c)+(a,b)) = (c'c,a'c+a, b'c+b)$.  This reflects the fact that if $G=NH$ with $N$ normal, then you can also express it as $G=HN$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\theta: \mathbb{F}^* \rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{F}^2)$ is a homomorphism such that $\forall c \in \mathbb{F}^*, \theta(c)=\theta_c$, where $\theta_c((a,b))=(ca,cb)$ for all $(a,b) \in \mathbb{F}^2$.

You can check that $\theta_c \in Aut(\mathbb{F}^2)$.

Now consider the isomorphism $\sigma:(\mathbb{F}^2,+) \rtimes_{\theta} \mathbb{F}^* \rightarrow G$, where $G$ is the group of matrices you mentioned, such that $$\sigma(((a,b),c))=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{a}{c} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{b}{c} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{c} \end{bmatrix}$$

We have

$$\sigma(((a',b'),c')((a,b),c))=\sigma((a',b')+\theta_{c'}((a,b)),c'c))=\sigma(((a',b')+(c'a,c'b),c'c))=\sigma(((a'+c'a,b'+c'b),c'c))=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{a'+c'a}{c'c} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{b'+c'b}{c'c} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{c'c} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{a'}{c'} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{b'}{c'} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{c'} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{a}{c} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{b}{c} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{c} \end{bmatrix}=\sigma(((a',b'),c'))\sigma(((a,b),c)).$$

You can also check that it is onto and one-to-one. Hence, $(\mathbb{F}^2,+) \rtimes_{\theta} \mathbb{F}^* \cong G$.

Comment: I'm not seeing what this shows.

Comment: It shows that the group of mentioned matrices is isomorphic to the semidirect product.